# Disable an <option> when already selected

Tags: javascript, php, database

How do I disable an option if someone already submits the form with that option.

```html
<select>
    <option value="1">Session 1</option>
    <option value="2">Session 2</option>
    <option value="3">Session 3</option>
</select>
```

For instance if session 2 has been selected by a user, I don't want it to be available when someone else tries to submit the form. I only want to have 1 user per session.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Uh, this doesn't sound like a JavaScript problem, unless you only expect users to submit the form from the same computer. I would suggest storing the submitted information on your server (probably in a database), then querying it and disabling options as needed using server code (like PHP) when the `<select>` is being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Serlite's comment. It's nearly impossible to do it purely with Javascript. You'd have to use a back-end server language like PHP. If you used PHP, you could give each option an id, and if that option has been previously submitted, (which you could pass in PHP or store that information in a database), make that option deactivated. I'd have to know more about what exactly you're trying to do to actually give you a code snippet. For example, what is the form used for? Are you submitting it to a database? etc.